# Not all line strings from same coordinates rendered in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, linestring, vector-layer

I am trying to make two vector lines, one is a `FlowLine` from `ol-ext`, the other is a simple `LineString`

```
function generate_line(points: number[][]){
  //Copy points into new array
  let array = points
  
  array.forEach((element, index) => {
    array[index] = olProj.fromLonLat(LatLon_to_LonLat(element))
  });

  let featureLine = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new geom.LineString(array)
  })

  let vectorLine = new source.Vector({})
  vectorLine.addFeature(featureLine)

  let lineStyle = new style.Style({
    stroke: new style.Stroke({
        color: '#FFFFFF',
        width: 20
    })
  });

  let vectorLineLayer = new layer.Vector({
    source: vectorLine,
    style: new style.Style({
      fill: new style.Fill({ color: '#00FF00' }),
      stroke: new style.Stroke({ color: '#00FF00', width: 20 })
  })
  })

  return vectorLineLayer
}
function generate_flowline(points: number[][]){
  let array = points
  
  array.forEach((element, index) => {
    array[index] = olProj.fromLonLat(LatLon_to_LonLat(element))
  });

  let featureLine = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new geom.LineString(array)
  })

  let vectorLine = new source.Vector({})
  vectorLine.addFeature(featureLine)

  let flowlineStyle: flowline_options = {
    width: 10,
    width2: 10,
    lineCap: "round",
    color: "#ff0049",
    color2: "#00d4ff"
  }

  let vectorLineLayer = new layer.Vector({
    source: vectorLine,
    style: new FlowLine(flowlineStyle)
  })

  return vectorLineLayer
}
```

My problem is that when I call

```
map.addLayer(generate_flowline(points))
map.addLayer(generate_line(points))
```

It only renders the first line provided, I also tried making a group and calling `map.setLayerGroup`, but it also renders only one line, is there any way to display two Vector Lines at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in this part of your line creating functions:

```
function generate_flowline(points: number[][]){
  let array = points
  
  array.forEach((element, index) => {
    array[index] = olProj.fromLonLat(LatLon_to_LonLat(element))
  });
```

When you create projected coordinates, you store them in the original array, so when this logic is used the second time, already projected coordinates are projected again.

Solution in simply to iterate `points` and store projected coordinates in a new array:

```
function generate_flowline(points: number[][]){
  let array = [];
  
  points.forEach((element, index) => {
    array[index] = olProj.fromLonLat(LatLon_to_LonLat(element))
  });
```

Also order of adding line strings should be reversed, since plain line string is wider than flow line string:

```
map.addLayer(generate_line(points))
map.addLayer(generate_flowline(points))
```

Comment: This was exactly my problem! Thank you very much! :)